# Messy dual boot with Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, mouse

OK. This seemed like simple problem to solve first but I couldn't find a solution.

A Dell PE machine had Windows Server 2012 first and I installed latest Ubuntu LTS on the machine with dual boot. But Grub menu automatically did not pick up the Windows Server OS but another windows 10 on one of hard drives it had. How can I make grub menu display the Windows server 2012?

As a side problem you don't have to answer, I cannot see mouse pointer for some reason. Looking at UI interaction from mouse move, I think it's there but the cursor is invisible. This additional mess makes the issue above really difficult to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I decided Ubuntu installation was wrong although I followed the same instruction used for other machines. Maybe Ubuntu is not for server hardware? I am not sure. Anyway in the end, I removed Ubuntu partitions after deleting Grub residue in bootloader by following:

1. boot from DVD of Windows Server 2012 R2 -> Repair System -> Command Prompt
2. At command prompt: diskpart -> list vol -> (find a bootloader volume with FAT partition) -> sel vol X (X: the volume number) -> assign letter=Z: -> exit
3. At command prompt: Z: -> bootrec.exe /fixmbr -> bootrec.exe /fixboot -> bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd -> It will ask which OS to include among detected OS -> I selected All -> close command prompt window -> Reboot the machine
4. You should be able to see OS boot selection menu.

Hope it helps others with similar problems.